# Azure Resource Manager and Powershell DSC - changes not being applied

Tags: powershell, azure, dsc

I have an ARM template with a Powershell DSC extension section running the following DSC:

```
Configuration Name
{
    Node MachineName
    {
        #IIS Role
        WindowsFeature IIS
        {
            Name = “Web-Server”
            Ensure = “Present”
        }

        #IIS GUI
        WindowsFeature WebServerManagementConsole
        {
            Name = "Web-Mgmt-Console"
            Ensure = "Present"
        }
    }
}
```

This runs fine and as expected. The problem occurs if I try to change anything (e.g. add a new WindowsFeature or change an Ensure option to "Absent"). These changes are not reflected on the server.

Is there a flag or option to enable ARM to push DSC changes to the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, the DSC extension does not apply changes to existing machines with previous versions of your DSC templates. The only way I have been able to get this to work is to delete the DSC extension and then re-run the ARM template to re-apply it, with your changes.

This is not the case if you use the Azure Automation pull server (so pull instead of push) this will pull new changes.